# Exception thrown with OneToMany annotation

Tags: jpa, playframework, ebean

In my Play 2.0 application using the EBean ORM I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String someString;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @OrderBy("index")
    public List<UserImage> userImages = new ArrayList<UserImage>();
}
```

Unless I comment out the `@OneToMany` line completely, the application throws a `RunTimeException` stating

> Error reading annotations for models.User

The `UserImage` class I refer to here looks like this:

```
public class UserImage extends Model {
    @Id
    public long id;

    @Constraints.Min(0)
    public int index;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    //...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't EBean understand my annotation?

Comment: Have you set `@Entity` annotation on the UserImage class (it is not shown on your sample code) ?

Comment: No, no I haven't. That's the solution. Ugh. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the `@Entity` annotation on the `UserImage class`:

```
@Entity
public class UserImage extends Model {
    @Id
    public long id;

    @Constraints.Min(0)
    public int index;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    //...
}
```